# Changing Maps In Game

Tags: file, game-development, windows-ce

I want to change the map in **Rainbow Six Siege** like when i start any map in custom game and load any other map.

Please Help

Example: I select House Map in custom game And Change something from cheat engine or change some hex codes then start i get bank map.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask about video games, please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Go to options and select matchmaking preferences then you can disable all the ones you don't want to play and leave on the ones you do. Effectively you can just do one map and one mode if you desire. This works for Lone Wolf and PVE. Video below shows how.

https://youtu.be/KUn-zdRob8M

hope u r satisfied with the answer

Comment: No No Im Trying To Change Map by file like there is 
 "datapc64_evn04_gangdestruction_events.forge" and trying to load i have tried changing the name searching by cheat engine (string) of file "datapc64_pvp01_house_v2" and changed to "datapc64_evn04_gangdestruction_events" this happend: https://i.ibb.co/qWJrbn2/Screenshot-73.png (IN CUSTOM GAME) with battleeye off

Comment: oh then i m sorry to say i cant help cz thats all i knew about it

Comment: its ok but still finding

Comment: thnk u@BrAtUkATutorials

Comment: no prob btw if you know someone modder i would really appreciate

Comment: yup i will try for sure :)